# MEF Import has Nothing

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I want to use mef to add plugins. And in the plugin, has something imported from other plugin added by main program, just like ioc?

now I can get this plugin successfully, but in the plugin can not get the imported one.

Following is my code. the log in plugin.Service is null.

**Interfaces Project**

*Ilog.cs*

```
public interface Ilog
{
    void Log(string log);
}
```

*IServece.cs*

```
public interface IService
{
    Ilog Log { get; }

    void DoSomeThing();
}
```

*IPlugin.cs*

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    string PluginName { get; }

    IService Service { get; }
}
```

**Plugin1 Project**

```
public class Plugin1Service : IService
{
    [Import(typeof(Ilog))]
    public Ilog Log { get; private set; }//todo:Log is null

    public void DoSomeThing()
    {
        Log.Log("test from Plugin1");
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
public class Plugin1Info : IPlugin
{
    public string PluginName => "Plugin1";

    public IService Service =>new Plugin1Service();
}
```

**ConsoleLog Porject**

```
[Export(typeof(Ilog))]
public class Console1 : Ilog
{
    public void Log(string log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(log);
    }
}
```

**Main Project**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var catalogs = new DirectoryCatalog(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalogs);

        var plugin = container.GetExportedValue<IPlugin>();
        Console.WriteLine($"{plugin.PluginName}");
        plugin.Service.DoSomeThing();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

when run the program, the log in plugin.Service is null *(can see 'todo:')* . How can I get the log item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your own service instance, so MEF does not provide an `ILog` instance.

When you let MEF create your service it will pick up on the Log property. So:

```
    [Export(typeof(IService))] // Add this export
    public class Plugin1Service : IService
    {
        [Import(typeof(Ilog))]
        public Ilog Log { get; private set; }//todo:Log is null

        public void DoSomeThing()
        {
            Log.Log("test from Plugin1");
        }
    }

    [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
    public class Plugin1Info : IPlugin
    {
        public string PluginName => "Plugin1";

        [Import] // Import the service
        public IService Service { get; set; }
    }
```

In case you HAVE to create the service yourself you can ask MEF to fill out all imports by calling `SatisfyImportsOnce` on the `CompositionContainer`.

Comment: Tanks to @Pidon , and I got that。